# Stripe js + React/JS accessing data after stripe redirect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, stripe-payments

In Netherlands, the popular payment method is Bancontact, and this method redirects the user to bank page where the user can either open bank app to pay or input credit card information

My question is the following in this example of code (this code will automatically push user to bank page):

```
stripe
  .confirmBancontactPayment('{PAYMENT_INTENT_CLIENT_SECRET}', {
    payment_method: {
      billing_details: {
        name: 'Jenny Rosen',
      },
    },
    // Return URL where the customer should be redirected after the authorization.
    return_url: window.location.href,
  })
  .then(function(result) {
    if (result.error) {
      // Inform the customer that there was an error.
    }
  });
```

After redirect, they access data inside following code:

```
.then(function(result) {
  if (result.error) {
    // Inform the customer that there was an error.
  }
});
```

Which doesn't make much sense because this is a refreshed page after user comes back from paying and JS state is refreshed since the

```
// Return URL where the customer should be redirected after the authorization.
return_url: window.location.href,
```

Did I miss a lesson in JS?

(code automatically redirects to bank page and brings user bank to your return url but `.then()` promise no longer exists)

**How do they access data after the user has been redirected and returned to refreshed page?**

*Stripe page: https://stripe.com/docs/js/payment_intents/confirm_bancontact_payment*

Comment: But the comment literally says: `Inform the customer that there was an error`. I guess no redirect is performed if there was an error, anything from a network connectivity problem to an internal server error, I believe, would cause that fragment to execute.

Answer (score 2):

When using `stripe.confirmBancontactPayment` the `.then` at the end is used to catch errors that happen prior to the customer being redirected to their bank (such as the redirect failing).  The `.then` code will not be called after a successful redirect.

> **How do they access data after the user has been redirected and returned to refreshed page?**

When calling `stripe.confirmBancontactPayment` you specify a `return_url` your customer will be sent to after the authorize the payment at the bank's website.  The `return_url` will have the following query parameters added:

- `payment_intent`
- `payment_intent_client_secret`

These values allow you to link the redirect back to the original Payment Intent.

For example, if you specify a `return_url` of `https://example.com/return` the customer will be sent to `https://example.com/return?payment_intent=pi_123&payment_intent_client_secret=pi_123_456`

This entire flow is covered in more detail in [Stripe's Bancontact Payments Guide](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/bancontact/accept-a-payment).